# Does VBA have an ATan2 function?

Tags: vba

I'd like to calculate `atan2` in VBA, but I'm not sure if that function exists (or even where to find a canonical list of built-in VBA functions).  I'm not using Excel so a worksheet call isn't possible.

I could [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162232/atan2-in-c-or-similar-lanaguge) `atan2` myself, but I'd prefer to avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this code would suit you:

```
Private Const Pi As Double = 3.14159265358979

Public Function Atn2(y As Double, x As Double) As Double
  If x > 0 Then
    Atn2 = Atn(y / x)
  ElseIf x < 0 Then
    Atn2 = Sgn(y) * (Pi - Atn(Abs(y / x)))
  ElseIf y = 0 Then
    Atn2 = 0
  Else
    Atn2 = Sgn(y) * Pi / 2
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: In VBA `Sgn(0)` is zero. Not sure the code above gives the correct answer if x<0 and y=0. It returns 0. Sgn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242074(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Why not just use WorksheetFunction.Atan2()?

Comment: @JohnSchultz - this is provided by Excel, not VBA

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by MarkJ earlier, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117642/8112776) will fail when X < 0 and y=0. I believe the following will work all the time:

```vb
Function ArcTan2(X As Double, Y As Double) As Double

    Private Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979
    Private Const PI_2 As Double = 1.5707963267949

    Select Case X
        Case Is > 0
            ArcTan2 = Atn(Y / X)
        Case Is < 0
            ArcTan2 = Atn(Y / X) + PI * Sgn(Y)
            If Y = 0 Then ArcTan2 = ArcTan2 + PI
        Case Is = 0
            ArcTan2 = PI_2 * Sgn(Y)
    End Select

End Function
```

It takes advantage of Sgn(0) returning 0 in the case where both x and y are 0.

Comment: The above assumes the standard order. Some languages seem to swap the inputs of the X and Y. See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2>

Comment: For reference, here's the same function, compressed into a "one-liner": `Function ATan2(X#,Y#)As Double:Const PI#=3.14159265358979:ATan2=IIf(X>0,Atn(Y/X),IIf(X<0,Atn(Y/X)+PI*Sgn(Y)+IIf(Y=0,PI,0),PI/2*Sgn(Y))):End Function`

Answer (score 6):

To get a list, type into your module

```
VBA.Math
```

Or use the object browser. You will find Atn and Tan, amongst others, but the list is quite short and ATan2 is not included.

If you wish to add a reference to an Excel library, you can use:

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Atan2
```

EDIT: You can call Excel worksheet functions from any Office application that allows you to add a reference to the Excel libraries. This does not mean using Excel or a worksheet, just the function.

Comment: I'm not using any Office product, and I can't assume that Office will be installed along with the product that's hosting my VBA macro.

Comment: In that case, you may be limited to VBA.Math functions, and they do not include ATan2. If it is not confidential, what are you using that includes VBA but is not part of the Office family? It is possible that it will have an extended set of functions, because each of MS applications is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
Application.Atan2
```