# Angle of rotation for a data label along a line on a chart

Tags: excel, vba, math, trigonometry

I have a chart that plots flow vs power. I want to adjust the rotation of a data label that sits on top of a line on the chart to match the slope of the line. The first point is plotted at 25000, 87000; the second point is plotted at 53000, 182000. If I manually count the gridlines and do Tangent(theta) = opposite / adj I get an answer that makes sense ~22º but if I use the actual data from the graph my angle is wrong. Eyeballing the graph, it looks like 22º but using the plot data it gives me 73º.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confusing opposite and adj. 73º is right answer for these data.

You have two points `P1 = (x1, y1)` and `P2 = (x2, y2)`.
Segment P1P2 has slope angle (in radians)

```
A = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
```

(I don't know exactly, whether `atan2` or `ArcTan2` function  exists in VBA math library - [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117265/does-vba-have-an-atan2-function) found)

Comment: MBo, I ran the numbers again for my sanity and you're right. I'm realizing now that the problem is a scaling issue. If I set both the x and y axis maximums to the same value angle looks perfect! however if the axis maximums are adjusted to show only the data, my angle changes. The revised question I suppose is if a graph has two different maximums how can I account for the scaling change.

Comment: Yes, to find angle, you should use graphic coordinates. not data values.